# iphone: Smart way to cache large number of images?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, image, ipad, caching

I have a UITableView that displays hundreds of images that are downloaded from the web. Of course I don't want to keep all the images in the RAM - I need to create a small "cache" of images in the RAM and write the images that I don't need right now to the "disk". Of course I don't want this mechanism to hinder the UI (Too many reads and writes to the disk/flash drive on the main thread). What's the best and easy way to implement such a thing? Are there any open source projects that use such a thing, I can look at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)
Very easy and elegant.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [Three20](http://three20.info) library, especially the TTURLRequest, TTURLCache and TTImageView classes.

Answer (score -1):

I have a class that stores the UIImage in a NSMutableDictionary. If the UIImage already exists in the dictionary then I just return that object rather than creating a new UIImage.

```
#import “Cache.h"
@implementation Cache

static NSMutableDictionary *dict;

+ (UIImage*)loadImageFromWeb:(NSString*)imageName{
    if (!dict) dict = [[NSMutableDictionary dictionary] retain];

    UIImage* image = [dict objectForKey:imageName];
    if (!image)
    {
        image = [UIImage imageWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString: imageName]]];
        if (image)
        {
            [dict setObject:image forKey:imageName];
        }
    }

    return image;
}
```

Comment: -1 That **would** keep all the images in RAM...which is what the poster _explicitly_ wanted to avoid.